# Which's differently on isfullscreen and isfullwindows on media player framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="YoutubePlayer" Visibility="Visible" IsFullScreenVisible="True" 
IsFullScreenChanged="YoutubePlayer_IsFullScreenChanged" 
Stretch="UniformToFill" MediaQuality="HighDefinition" 
IsResolutionIndicatorVisible="True" IsSignalStrengthVisible="False" IsAudioSelectionVisible="True" IsPlayPauseVisible="True" 
IsSkipAheadVisible="True" IsSkipBackVisible="True" 
MediaOpened="YoutubePlayer_MediaOpened" 
MediaEnded="YoutubePlayer_MediaEnded" 
MediaQualityChanged="YoutubePlayer_MediaQualityChanged" ></mmppf:MediaPlayer>

private async void YoutubePlayer_IsFullScreenChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
            dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

1. `isfullwindows = true`

   > then video plays on fullwindow but be lost control(play,pause...) athough I had touch on screen.
2. `isfullscreen ==true`

   > it will be not play on fullwindows because of media player framework lies inside grid.

Means `<grid width=300 height=400>` and then media player framework will play fullsreen of grid(media player framework.width=300...)

**Note:** On `XAML` are getting much `grid` tags

my ways is create new pages and just show video. but I don't want do that. It look bad.

How to solve it? I want play on fullwindow but still keep an control(play, pause...).